# Android Studio Local Git Repository

Tags: android, git

I have been trying to run Git fro Android Studio for two days now.  What I would really appreciate are references to books or good tutorials that cover Git in the Android Studio context.  What I want to do:
1.  Set up a LOCAL repository (Think I got that one)
2.  Perform an initial commit
3.  Push changes to the repository.

All from within Android Studio

Thanks for any help!

Bill

Comment: I doubt that Android Studio has changed this a lot over what is in IntelliJ IDEA, on which Android Studio is based. So, you might poke around for some IDEA instructions and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that was the tip I needed.  Still can't make the Initial Commit from within AS, but I can use git-gui to do it.